# setting command in the model for the list view

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am setting command in my model as follow

```
Settings test = new Settings();

private Command _navigate;
    public Command Navigate
    {
      set { SetProperty(ref _navigate, value); }
      get { return _navigate; }
    }
```

then I am adding it to my collection

```
 private void LoadGeneralSetting()
    {
      foreach ( var setting in _customSettings.GeneralSettings )
      {
        var detail = new Settings()
        {
          Type = setting.Type,
          Index = setting.Index,
          IsSelected = setting.Value,
          Navigate = new Command(GeneralSettingNavigation(null))
        };
        GeneralSetting.Add(detail);
      }
    }
```

and then the method

```
  private void GeneralSettingNavigation(object sender)
    {
      Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ThemeSelection());
    }
```

however I am getting underline "Cannot resolve constructor 'Command(void)', candidates are: Command(System.Action) (in class Command) Command(System.Action) (in class Command)"

can you please advise what am I doing wrong I have tried null setting object.. just a string but still the same outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because the constructor for `Command` requires an `Action`, just like the error message is telling you

```
Navigate = new Command(() => { GeneralSettingNavigation(null); })
```